# Customize Devise Cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise in my rails application. I have it configured in a tenanted manor in which accounts/sessions are scoped to a subdomain. For example:

```
http://subdomain1.example.com/
http://subdomain2.example.com/
...
```

This works well but I want to have an additional subdomain for "super-admins" that allows those users navigate to all the other subdomains without the need to reauthenticate. This would be something like:

```
http://admin.example.com/
```

Is it possible to customize the cookie that gets generated on only the admin subdomain so that it is valid on all other subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie domains are more inclusive the less specifically they are defined, so if you have a controller that only serves the admin subdomain, you should be able to set a cookie for the `.example.com` (or `example.com`) domain and expect it to be available to all other subdomains.

[These docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-subdomains) describe the process for selectively setting the cookie domain.